# R code for convolution of multiple random variables

Tags: r

I am trying to empirically prove the central limit theorem by adding a simple uniform distribution multiple times.

I have mostly worked with VBA before so the naturally I used a for loop, however I am curious if there is any way to simplify the code in R, as I would like to be able to run it up to at least 50 times. Code is shown below:

```
A <- seq(1,8,1)
B <- seq(1,8,1)
C <- seq(1,8,1)
D <- seq(1,8,1)


p.Z <- as.integer()

for(a in 1:8){
    for(b in 1:8){
        for(c in 1:8){
            for(d in 1:8){
                Z <- A[a] + B[b] + C[c] + D[d]
                p.Z <- c(p.Z, Z)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the statistics behind it but the code can definitely be simplified using `expand.grid` and `rowSums`. `expand.grid` creates all combinations of input vector.

```
p1 <- rowSums(expand.grid(1:8, 1:8, 1:8, 1:8))
```

Comparing it with `p.Z` from OP's `for` loop

```
identical(p1, p.Z)
#[1] TRUE
```

To do this dynamically, we can use `do.call` with `replicate`

```
n <- 4
rowSums(do.call(expand.grid, replicate(n, 1:8, simplify = FALSE)))
```

---

The same behavior can also be achieved using `crossing` from `tidyr`

```
rowSums(tidyr::crossing(a = 1:8, b = 1:8, c = 1:8, d = 1:8))
```

Comment: Thats great thank you, but how can I edit the code to make it so it is not limited to only 4 variables. So if I want to do ```p1 <- rowSums(expand.grid(1:8, 1:8, 1:8, 1:8,1:8..........n))```

Comment: @SergeKashlik okay..Added an update using `do.call` and `replicate`

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
p1 <- Reduce(`+`, expand.grid(rep(list(1:8), 4)))
all.equal(p1, p.Z)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or with `CJ` from `data.table`

```
CJ(a = 1:8, b = 1:8, c = 1:8, d = 1:8)[, Reduce(`+`, .SD)]
```